# Pasar data/variable PHP a modal Bootstrap 3 desde path de SVG

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, svg

Tengo esto que lanza una modal Bootstrap 3 con un input que recoge el valor de **data-id** pero no me funciona cuando la pido desde el path de SVG, **me lanza la modal correctamente**, pero sin el valor **data-id.**

**Sin embargo desde un enlace corriente sí.** Alguien sabe si estoy ignorando algún tipo de elemento de SVG?

```
<svg id="svgCapa83346623" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: inline; width: 100%; height: 88%;background-color:#c7e6f6;margin-top:25px;" version="1.1">
<a data-id="mi variable o dato" id="modal-918098" href="#modal-container-918098" class="open-AddBookDialog" data-toggle="modal">

        <path id="12345678"class="inactius" d="m 158.50293,69.162684 -0.47152,0.235741 -0.70725,-0.707224 -2.12177,1.178717 z" 
        onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute(\'opacity\', \'0.5\');" 
        onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute(\'opacity\', \'1\');"></path>
        </a>
 </svg>   


    <!--modal-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-container-918098" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>


    <script>
        $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var _self = $(this);

        var myBookId = _self.data('id');
        $("#bookId").val(myBookId);

        $(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Probé tu código y me funciona perfectamente, me aparece el modal con el input y su valor "mi variable o dato", incluso sin corregir el escape de los eventos onmouseover y onmouseout también me funciona.

Comment: Sí, si lo lanzas desde un enlace normal, pero no al hacerlo desde dentro del svg path. Prueba a pinchar en cualquier municipio de este enlace. http://www.webentorn.com/municipis/test.php. El dato es "joselito"

Comment: No, lo probé desde un svg path, tal y como está tu código. Voy a hacer otra prueba ahora que veo tu código completo.

Comment: Ok, pero he modificado la página test debido a tema laboral. Disculpa la molestia.

Comment: Lo que no veo es como agregas el data-id al `a`, haces una solicitud ajax?

Comment: No, esa etiqueta pasa el dato directamente (HTML5) <a href="" data-id="dato">link</a>

Comment: No entiendo lo que me quieres decir, ayer cuando miré tu código, no estaba ese atributo en el código como tal `data-id="...."`.

Comment: te pido disculpas, Shaz, tuve que cambiar el código por temas laborales. Te agradezco el seguimiento. mi solución ha sido enlazar con un link directo a una página detalle.